Iterating through range, creating new sheet, error when creating new sheet
Sub CreateNewWorksheet()
'Go to the open column, reformat the information in column C
'Copy and paste that information into new column
'Make new sheets based off a list made of unique entries
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("CopiedSheet")
' Determine the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Set the range from A1 to the last row in column A
    Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
' Enter the formula into the range; this will display each date by month
    rng.Formula = "=TEXT(RC[-1], ""mmmm"")" ' Pastes formula into cells

    Dim Branchfield As Range 'Creates a variable named Branchfield and sets it to Range
    Dim BranchName As Range 'BranchName is the placeholder variable for the value inside the cell
    Dim WSheetFound As Boolean 'True/False Variable based on whether or not a sheet is found
    
    Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataWSheet As Worksheet 'The Worksheet that has our original data
    'Dim String
    
    Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("CopiedSheet") 'Sets all the information in CopiedSheet to the variable DataWSheet
    Set Branchfield = DataWSheet.Range("D2", DataWSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)) 'Holds the months
    
    For Each BranchName In Branchfield
    'Check whether the current branch name corresponds with an existing sheet
        For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            'MsgBox WSheet.Name
            If WSheet.Name = BranchName Then
                WSheetFound = True
                BranchName.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 13).Copy Destination:=WSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
                Exit For ' If it does assign True to the WSheet Found variable
            Else
                WSheetFound = False 'if it doesn't assign False to the WSheet
            End If
        Next WSheet
    
        If WSheetFound = True Then 'if WSheetFound = True
            
        Else 'if WSheetFound = False
            Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 'insert new worksheet
            NewWSheet.Name = BranchName 'named after that branch
            DataWSheet.Range("A1", DataWSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A1") 'and copy the headings to it
            BranchName.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 13).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A2") ' then copy and paste the record to i
        
        End If
     '   Next WSheet
    Next BranchName
        
End Sub

My code iterates through a range, but when it gets to the 20th (or so) value, it tries to create a new sheet. Excel realizes that there is already a sheet with that name, and the code breaks. I'm totally lost and don't know why this is, please help!


Is there a chance that ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook are two different workbooks at that point in execution? You search the former to see if the sheet exists, but you add the sheet to the latter. It's not 100% that those are the same.

Have you checked that BranchName contains a valid sheet name?

Create Monthly Sheets
A Quick Fix

You forgot to reset the flag (Boolean variable):
If WSheetFound Then ' exists; already processed
    WSheetFound = False ' reset for the next iteration
Else ' doesn't exist; not processed




An Improvement
Sub CreateMonthlySheets()

    ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "CopiedSheet"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const SRC_LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "A"
    ' The following two have to be adjacent since '-1' in the formula. 
    Const SRC_DATE_COLUMN As String = "C"
    Const SRC_MONTH_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const MONTH_FORMULA As String = "=TEXT(RC[-1], ""mmmm"")"
    Const US_MONTH_FORMULA As String = "=TEXT(RC[-1], ""[$-409]mmmm"")"
    Const FORCE_US_MONTHS As Boolean = False

    ' Create references to the main objects (workbook, worksheet, ranges).
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    Dim WasAutofiltered As Boolean: WasAutofiltered = sws.AutoFilterMode
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' list
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
    
    If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1) ' data
    
    ' Write the month formula to the month column and return the resulting
    ' values in an array.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim mData() As Variant, MonthColumn As Long
    
    With sdrg.Columns(SRC_MONTH_COLUMN)
        ' Write month formula.
        .Formula = IIf(FORCE_US_MONTHS, US_MONTH_FORMULA, MONTH_FORMULA)
        ' Return the values of the month column in an array.
        If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell (row)
            ReDim mData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): mData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else ' multiple cells (rows)
            mData = .Value
        End If
        ' Get the column index (number).
        MonthColumn = .Column
    End With
    
    ' Return the unique values (months) from the month array
    ' in the keys of a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        dict(mData(sr, 1)) = Empty
    Next sr
    
    ' Delete existing monthly sheets.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, Key As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if sheet doesn't exist
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                wb.Sheets(Key).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next Key
    On Error Goto 0
    
    ' Copy data filtered by months to newly created monthly sheets.
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        dws.Name = Key
        Set dcell = dws.Range("A1")
        srg.AutoFilter MonthColumn, Key
        srg.Rows(1).Copy
        dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dcell
        Application.Goto Reference:=dcell, Scroll:=True
        sws.ShowAllData
    Next Key
    
    ' Clean up.
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = WasAutofiltered
    Application.Goto Reference:=srg.Cells(1), Scroll:=True
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Monthly sheets created.", vbInformation
       
End Sub


I copied replaced my code with yours, but I'm getting a Runtime Error 9,  Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME) is what is messing it up, any suggestions? (Thanks for your help)
